# Python SpacePy Library CDF File Epoch to Datetime 'Function Undefined' Error

Tags: python, arrays, database, function, epoch

I am currently conducting research related to the NASA THEMIS Satellite All-Sky-Imager Database. The database files are in .cdf format, so I am using Python 3.7.3 SpacePy library on my Linux CentOS 7 to read these CDF files and extract data. I use the Python3 console within the Linux terminal.

```
>>> import spacepy
# Defining the CDF Object File
>>> cdf = pycdf.CDF('/projectnb/burbsp/big/SATELLITE/themis/data/thg/l1/asi/gill/2008/01/thg_l1_asf_gill_2008011403_v01.cdf')
```

```
# Reading the CDF Object File Components
>>> print(cdf)

range_epoch:CDF_EPOCH [2] 
thg_asf_gill: CDF_UINT2 [1198, 256, 256]
thg_asf_gill_column: CDF_UINT2 [256] NRV
thg_asf_gill_epoch: CDF_EPOCH [1198]
thg_asf_gill_epoch0: CDF_EPOCH [] NRV
thg_asf_gill_row: CDF_UINT2 [256] NRV
thg_asf_gill_tend: CDF_REAL8 [1198]
thg_asf_gill_time: CDF_REAL8 [1198]
```

In particular, I'm interested in extracting the date and time of an individual epoch within the CDF file. According to the [SpacePy library](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/autosummary/spacepy.pycdf.Library.html#spacepy.pycdf.Library.epoch_to_datetime), the Epoch to Date-time conversion is defined by this function:

```
spacepy.pycdf.epoch_to_datetime(epoch)
```

I use the same function to extract the date-time of the first epoch within .cdf file by writing:

```
>>> spacepy.pycdf.epoch_to_datetime(cdf['thg_asf_gill'][0,:,:])
```

As a result, I get this error:

> AttributeError: module 'spacepy.pycdf' has no attribute 'epoch_to_datetime'

I tried to handle the error by assigning a variable with the function, but I got the same error, so it must be a problem with the function itself or perhaps I'm missing something. It would help me a lot if anyone has encountered this problem before and knows what's wrong!

Comment: Did you import SpacePy? if so, how (`import spacepy` vs `from spacepy import *`)?

Comment: Yep, I imported SpacePy using ```import spacepy```

Comment: Please show that in the post. That said, unfortunately, I'm not familiar with SpacePy, but I suspect you need to make your call along the lines of `spacepy.epoch_to_datetime(...)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I looked at the library again and it seems like ```spacepy.pycdf.epoch_to_datetime(...)``` is the correct syntax to be used. However, once I use this, I get another error; I've updated the post ^ you can check the new error, and let me know what you think!

Comment: Glad I could help. That said, please keep questions focused on one issue; i.e. don't change the question to deal with a separate problem; instead, ask another question. That said, the AttributeError indicates that there is nothing by that name. In looking at the documentation, I suspect you need to change the call to `space.pycdf.Library.epoch_to_datetime(...)`.

Comment: I see, thank you that solves it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After GreenMatt helped me out, it turned out to be a syntax-related issue, the function should be written as:

```
spacepy.pycdf.Library.epoch_to_datetime(epoch)
```

It's also acceptable to write it in this form:

```
pycdf.Library.epoch_to_datetime(epoch)
```

I discovered that there's an easier way to extract the time. Apparently NASA has already included the date-time as one of the objects in the .cdf file, it's the object with the extension _epoch. So, a quick way to extract the date-time is by writing (in my case):

```
# Extracting datetime of the first epoch from the .cdf file
>>> epoch = cdf['thg_asf_gill_epoch'][0]
>>> print(epoch)
2008-01-14 03:00:00.067000
```

As you can see it gives the hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds, and so on... So it's a great way to know precisely the datetime of the fragment of data your extracting. Hope this helps anyone who might be stuck in the future like I was! Thank you @GreenMatt for your help.